# How to change the label color in Telerik UI for WinForms using radchartview

Tags: winforms, telerik, bar-chart

How to change the color of labels in Barseries using Telerik UI for winforms? 
In the attached chart, i want to set the background color of labels to white. I am creating the chart in server side and exporting to image.

[Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7xfl.png)
Example of code :

```
 var radChartView = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadChartView();

 var barSeries = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.BarSeries();  
    barSeries.LabelMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.BarLabelModes.Top;  
    barSeries.ShowLabels = true;
    radChartView.Series.Add(barSeries);
 var stream = new MemoryStream();
    radChartView.ExportToImage(stream, radChartView.Size,   
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Telerik website:

```
private Font font1 = new Font("Segoe Script", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
private void radChartView1_LabelFormatting(object sender, ChartViewLabelFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    e.LabelElement.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#005BBc");
    e.LabelElement.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#91c930");
    e.LabelElement.BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ee8310");
    e.LabelElement.Font = font1;
    CategoricalPointElement element = (CategoricalPointElement)e.LabelElement.Parent;
    CategoricalDataPoint dataPoint = (CategoricalDataPoint)element.DataPoint;
    e.LabelElement.Text = string.Format("Category: {0}, Value: {1}", dataPoint.Category, dataPoint.Value);
}
```

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/chartview/customization/formatting-series-labels

Comment: did you subscribe to the event?

Comment: how to subscribe to it?

Comment: in the design mode select the chart control, open its settings and click the lightning icon. Find the LabelFormatting event and double click

Comment: I am creating the  chart in server side and exporting it to image in a controller using Telerik dll.

Comment: smth like that: this.radChartView.LabelFormatting += new System.EventHandler(this.radChartView_LabelFormatting);

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  i  was able to implement it in c#, but in vb LabelFormatting event is not thr